# Salesforce Data Mask and Workflows / Process Builder deactivation

Tags: security, data, salesforce-data-mask

I'm trying out Salesforce's Data Mask feature and in the docs (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_mask_considerations.htm&type=5) it mentions that all workflows (and presumably process builders) are deactivated upon a masking run.  However I don't see anything about these being re-activated upon completion.

Is this really a manual task that must be done after each data mask job?

Answer (score 1):

NO, the workflows, process builders and triggers do NOT need to be manually activated.  What the documentation is telling you (implicitly) is that the DML required to mask the data (by SFDC) will not cause any side effects via the execution of automation that normally occurs upon DML:

- Triggers
- WFR
- Process Builder
- Lightning Flow (before update, after update)

In a way, it is similar to the picklist item replace function which doesn't execute any automation on the affected records

Comment: Hmm thanks @cropredy!  Must be a bug then as all of our workflows / process builders were left as Inactive when the data mask job failed.

Comment: How did the masking job fail?

Comment: `First error: Apex heap size too large: 24187971` : Resolved after limiting the number of Objects we masked

Comment: Ah.  That would be a limits exception.  Sounds like a bug if mask job gets limits exception and doesn't reactivate triggers and PB.  You should file a support tix unless it is already a Known Issue

Comment: Ticket opened and being worked!